# Python: Return Average on unique values based on multiple columns

Tags: python

I have a data set that is looks like this, and there are instances in which there are multiple duplicates (ex.Gone Girl is repeated twice). I am not proficient at Python so I don't have any code at the moment and have tried looking all over stackoverflow.

But my objective is:

1. Remove all the duplicates and count how many times the author has written a book (ex. JK Rowling has written 2 different books and the other have all written 1)
2. Based on the unique books, what is the average rating of the author (ex. JK Rowlings would be (4.9+4.7)/2 = 4.55

Appreciate any help

| Book Name | Author | User Rating |
| --- | --- | --- |
| The Casual Vacancy | JK Rowling | 4.9 |
| Cabin Fever (Diary of a Wimpy Kid, Book 6) | Jeff Kinney | 3.9 |
| Harry Potter | JK Rowling | 4.7 |
| Cabin Fever (Diary of a Wimpy Kid, Book 6) | Jeff Kinney | 4.4 |
| Gone Girl | Gillian Flynn | 4.0 |
| Gone Girl | Gillian Flynn | 4.0 |
| The Girl on the Train) | Paula Hawkins | 4.1 |

Comment: 4.9+4.7/2 = 4.8

Comment: Depends on in which format you have the data …

Comment: Took the wrong value. but thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how you'd like the output format, but here is a way to drop duplicate books by the same author, and return the average score of the author after duplicate removal using the pandas library:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('mydata.txt', sep='\t') # use this if it is a tab delimited text file
df = pd.read_csv('mydata.csv') # use this if it is a comma separated value file

subset = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Book Name', 'Author']).groupby('Author').agg({"User Rating": "mean"})
print(subset)
```

outputs:

```
               User Rating
Author
Gillian Flynn     4.0
Feff Kinney       3.9
JK Rowling        4.8
Paula Hawkins     4.1
```

Explanations:

First, I am creating a [pandas dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) using the pandas library. If the data is in tab delimited text format, use the first line `df = pd.read_csv('mydata.txt', sep='\t')` to read in the data. If the data is in comma separated value format, use the second line `df = pd.read_csv('mydata.csv')` to read in the data. This creates the dataframe.

Then, `df.drop_duplicates` drops duplicate entries in a dataframe. If you select a `subset` it will look for duplicates of the subset passed. So in this case, I passed a list of two columns where I wanted to drop duplicates `['Book Name', 'Author']`. When you pass multiple columns, both of them have to be identical for it to be counted as a duplicate.

Then, I `groupby` the `'Author'`  column which will perform an `agg` or aggregation, to get the `mean` of the `User Rating` column, for each `'Author'`.

Comment: I think you should mention that this solutions needs `pandas`.

Comment: Good call. Added it with hopefully some clear explanations.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help and detailed explanation! I am starting to learn python and this really is a big help!! cant appreciate it enough

Comment: @briguy no problem at all, happy to help! If you feel like this successfully answered your question, feel free to mark it by clicking the "check mark" underneath the votes so future visitors will know that this is helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I would use `df.groupby(...).mean()` 2 times, to be consistent if, for an author, there are multiple books of which some have multiple ratings. But, the specifications may differ.

1. Calculate the mean note for each 'Author', 'Book Name' couple

   If for a couple the User Ratings are the same, that waste some ressources with no arm.
2. Calculate the mean note by author

the code is :

```
df.groupby(['Author', 'Book Name']]).mean().groupby(['Author']).mean()
```

with value :

```
               User Rating
Author                    
Gillian Flynn         4.00
JK Rowling            4.80
Jeff Kinney           4.15
Paula Hawkins         4.10
```

Comment: @GoldenLion , I explained it in the answer: it deals with the cases where , for an author, there are multiple books of which some have multiple ratings. the first groupby calculates the note for the book, then the second one for the author.